# How do I find difference between times in different timezones in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am trying to calculate difference(in seconds) between two date/times formatted as following:

2010-05-11 17:07:33 UTC

2010-05-11 17:07:33 EDT

```
time1 = '2010-05-11 17:07:33 UTC'
time2 = '2010-05-11 17:07:33 EDT'
delta = time.mktime(time.strptime(time1,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"))-\
        time.mktime(time.strptime(time2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"))
```

The problem I got is EDT is not recognized, the specific error is

```
ValueError: time data '2010-05-11 17:07:33 EDT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

Comment: Are you looking for this http://labix.org/python-dateutil ?  It might be simpler than whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
But even by using pytz I still could not figure out a better way to parse the string 'EDT' etc and convert it to an obj of pytz the timezone can be any 3-4 letter string abbreviations but pytz use 'US/Eastern'.
Do I need to build a mapping to convert the abbreviations to 'US/Eastern' format? It sounds too much to me.

Thanks,

Comment: I end up building a text file with entries like following:


<< EDT  Eastern Daylight Time (North America)  UTC-04 >>


Then search for the entry using string 'EDT' got from the time string
By using the value -04 in the file I can use mktime() to get the time difference in seconds. 

I still think there should be a easier way to do it...

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [**pytz**](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) world timezone definitions library.

> This library allows accurate and cross platform timezone calculations using Python 2.3 or higher. It also solves the issue of ambiguous times at the end of daylight savings, which you can read more about in the Python Library Reference (datetime.tzinfo).

It takes advantage of the [**tz database**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), which should include EDT, and allow you to perform the calculations you need to (and probably more reliably & accurately than your current implementation).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `pytz`, check out [`python-dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). The [`relativedelta`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) functionality is outstanding.

Here's a sample of using them together:

```
from datetime import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import *
import pytz

if __name__ == '__main__':
    date_one = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
    date_two = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Mountain'))
    rdelta = relativedelta(date_one, date_two)
    print(rdelta)
```

Comment: this is false... relativedelta doesn't account for timezones. I just tried it and this gives me 2 secondes difference between London and Paris (2secs = the time i needed to type the function)

Comment: Doesn't work, gives no difference between both dates.

Comment: It doesn't work. If the two dates are in different timezones, an error is raised: "Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones"

Answer (score 0):

From docs for [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime)

> Support for the %Z  directive is based
>   on the values contained in tzname and
>   whether daylight  is true. Because of
>   this, it is platform-specific except
>   for recognizing UTC and GMT which are
>   always known (and are considered to be
>   non-daylight savings timezones).