# Converting and calculating timezone for datetime objects in python with proper dates

Tags: python, pytz

How can we find time difference between two different time zones?
what i mean is,if i have two different times of different time zones:

d1=datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 7, 22, 30, tzinfo='Asia/Kolkata' LMT+5:53:00 STD>)

d2=datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 8, 5, 0, tzinfo='Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' LMT+6:47:00 STD>)
relativedelta(d2,d1) is relativedelta(hours=+5, minutes=+36)

But it is 4hr 0m ,Its failing here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find difference between times in different timezones in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828158/how-do-i-find-difference-between-times-in-different-timezones-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

**Add time zone information to a naive datetime object**

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

date_str = "2017-05-05 22:28:15"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime_obj_utc = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
print datetime_obj_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z")
```

Results:

```
2009-05-05 22:28:15 UTC+0000
```